# Repeating a goto only 15 times

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

```
echo off
:abc
Echo ^ text ^ >> C:/files/text_%random%.txt
goto abc
```

How do I do the `goto` only 15 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `goto` multiple times, you should use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Here, you can specify that the loop should run 15 times.

```
echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /L %%i in (1,1,15) do (Echo ^ text ^ >> C:/files/text_!random!.txt)
```

The variable `%%i` will be equivalent to 1, 2, …, but it will not be used inside the loop.

Comment: Akina, it would be good if your answer was not just a piece of code, but if you explained what you did in order to get rid of `goto` statements, and why your answer is better.

Comment: @slhck I solve the task rather than edit author's solution. This is not a learning task, using goto is not a dogma. I think so...

Comment: What I meant is, on Stack Exchange, we prefer answers that give a little explanation rather than just posting a piece of code. If someone else happens to find your answer, they might learn something from it (i.e. why is a `for` loop better in this case?).

Comment: @slhck English is not my native language so it's difficult for me to explain such things for novices. When I try to do it I obtain the explaination with a 'specialist level' - but those specialist have no problems to understand.

Comment: Hope [this](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) will be of help/ref of some sort.. ( :

Comment: I think Akina's answer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do the goto only 15 times?

`FOR /L %%v in (start, step, end) do *something*` will do what you need, but if you like using GOTO for this task, you can first set a variable equal to a start value, then increment (or decrement) it each time the repeated operation is performed, testing each time if it has reached the end value. Note that you can start an `echo off` line with the `@` symbol to prevent it being echoed to the console.

```
@echo off
set numval=0
REM you can use a variable or else a magic number in the loop
set endval=15
:abc
Echo ^ text ^ >> C:/files/text_%random%.txt
set /a numval +=1
if %numval% lss %endval% goto abc
REM or if %numval% lss 15 goto abc
echo Done 15 times
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line in command line:

```py
@cmd /v /c "for /L %l in (1 1 15)do @Echo ^ text ^ >>"C:/files/text_!random!.txt""
```